# Using oracle apex dynamic action to set a date time value that is concatenated

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-apex

I have a date value in one page item and i have a time value in another. i want to concat the date with the time and set it to another item using a dynamic action. Structure as below

P_DATE = '01-01-2021' (item is a date with format mask dd-mm-yyyy)

P_TIME = '08:30 AM' (item is date with format mask HH:MIAM)

Query:

```
select to_date(to_char(to_date(P_DATE ,'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YYYY') || ' '|| 
to_char(P_TIME,'HH:MIAM'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MIAM') a
from dual;
```

Desired Outcome: 01-01-2021 08:30 AM

Dynamic action is on change the P_DATE item then from an sql query, concat the P_DATE and P_TIME and set it to P_VALUE

When i run the select in sql developer with hardcoded values then it returns the correct stuff but when i try to set the value in the item with the concat date it giving me invalid number error sometimes and not a valid month.

Can you suggest the corrected way or an alternative way of doing this (maybe use a function)

THank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "they are date items" ? Are they of the type "Date Picker" , do they have a source column of type "DATE" in a form, or do they map to a DATE column in the database ?

In APEX, all page items are basically strings. The frontend of the web application doesn't know about oracle datatypes so everything is treated as a plain string and during the processing the conversion is done. So that is how you should treat the page items, not as DATE data type like you would in SQL or PL/SQL. To concatenate a date string and a time string, you can just a plain concatenate without `TO_CHAR`. This can be done in plain PL/SQL, no need to `SELECT FROM DUAL` - that is just an unnecessary call to the SQL engine.

This is the "true" action on the change of P_VALUE. Tested on 21.1, so depending on your version there might be some attribute naming differences but it works the same.

Action: execute server side code.
Source:

```
:P_VALUE := :P_DATE ||' '||:P_TIME
```

Items to submit: P_DATE, P_TIME.
Items to return: P_VALUE

Since you're dealing with strings there is room for error here, you'll have to ensure proper error handling if the user input does not exactly match the format since that could generate invalid date values.

Answer (score 2):

You can make that much simpler, example

```
with test as (
       select '01-01-2021' d, '08:30 PM' t 
       from dual)
select to_date(d||' '|| t,'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI PM') 
from test;
```

Comment: Sorry i didnt have this information at the top, i will edit the post but in this answer you are considering the date and time to be varchar but in actuality the page items are both date items

Answer (score 1):

From comments:

> the page items are both date items

Since they are dates, you can simply use:

```sql
SELECT p_date + (p_time - TRUNC(p_time)) AS a
FROM   DUAL;
```

Comment: This fails for me:

WITH test AS
 (SELECT '01-01-2021' p_date,
         '08:30 PM' p_time
    FROM dual)
SELECT p_date + (p_time - TRUNC(p_time)) AS a
  FROM test;

ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: @StewS2 `'01-01-2021'` and `'08:30 PM'` are both string literals, they are **NOT** a date data type. As I said on the first line, this answer is for when both items are dates which was the problem the OP had.